# Mysql Join After SELECT

Tags: mysql

I need to select 50 items that satisfy search criteria from the item list.
I also need current quantity of them on sales.
Item list has more than 100 000 records

This is what i do now:

```
SELECT 
  items.id,
  CONCAT(prod_codes.code,items.item) AS item,
  items.price,
  sold.count
FROM items
LEFT JOIN prod_codes ON items.prod_code_id=prod_codes.id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS count,CONCAT(prod_code,part_num) AS part 
    FROM `sold_items` 
    WHERE 1 
    GROUP BY CONCAT(prod_code,part_num)
    ORDER BY count DESC
) AS sold ON sold.part=CONCAT(prod_codes.code,items.item)
WHERE active_status=1
AND CONCAT(items.prod_code,items.item) collate utf8_general_ci LIKE '%".$search_part."%' 
AND items.description collate utf8_general_ci LIKE '%".$search_desc."%'

ORDER BY items.item

LIMIT 50
```

But this query takes over 20 seconds to execute. I'm sure there is better way to do it.

Comment: Why `GROUP BY CONCAT(prod_code,part_num)` and not `GROUP BY prod_code, part_num` ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of nesting a subquery, you may try this:

```
SELECT 
  items.id,
  CONCAT(prod_codes.code,items.item) AS item,
  items.price,
  COUNT(*) AS count
FROM items
LEFT JOIN prod_codes ON items.prod_code_id = prod_codes.id
LEFT JOIN sold_items sold ON sold.prod_code = prod_codes.code AND sold.part_num = items.item
WHERE active_status = 1
AND CONCAT(items.prod_code,items.item) collate utf8_general_ci LIKE '%".$search_part."%' 
AND items.description collate utf8_general_ci LIKE '%".$search_desc."%'
ORDER BY items.item
GROUP BY prod_codes.code, items.item, items.id, items.price
LIMIT 50
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this part of your WHERE clause

```
CONCAT(items.prod_code,items.item) collate utf8_general_ci LIKE '%".$search_part."%'
```

with this:

```
(items.prod_code collate utf8_general_ci LIKE '%".$search_part."%' OR items.item collate utf8_general_ci LIKE '%".$search_part."%')
```

That CONCAT() call is almost certainly bogging it down, because it can't use an index.

Also, you have SQL injection problems, etc. -- use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Finally, see @ypercube's comment; it's also a good point and will have a big impact.

Comment: But this is not the same as the first one. Anyone even if you disregard CONCAT part at all it is still slow.(just searching py part number only)

Comment: Did you try both my change and @ypercube's change?  Both of those CONCAT() calls are problems.

Comment: Any search 'contains' with *field like '%search%'* is not using indexes. Therefore a real enhancement would be a search begins with *field like 'search%'*

Comment: after i simplified it & remover both concats it is still 13 seconds verses 20. Without the subquery it executes much faster